# The length of a line in Torah scroll

Tags: halacha, history, sefer-torah

Looking at different fragments of ancient and contemporary scrolls, I wondered
What are the considerations of determining the length of a line in Torah scroll/Chumash?

[image]
*Dead Sea Scrolls*

[image]

*the Damascus Pentateuch*

[image]

*Contemporary Kosher Torah scroll*

Comment: Why do you think a chumash has any considerations as to its line width?

Comment: Chumashim typically just try to get everything to fit in the length of scroll or amount of paper available. And I recommend again [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23437895?refreqid=excelsior%3Af16eda928d4dd61a4afe43e7f87e2338&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) essay by Yosi Baruchi. Also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajk5mMHehRA) class by him on the same topic.

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure the DSS pic you brought isn't a Torah/Chumash scroll.

Comment: @Harel13 THis could be extra Biblical.

Comment: Which means that it's anyone's guess whether the sect that composed it had standards for extra-biblical scrolls.

Comment: @Harel13 It looks much more like a regular chumash with fancy lettering.

Comment: @N.T. While that may be, this particular DSS is not a chumash scroll. I can't make out all of the words, but at the very least, the word בממשלת does not appear in Tanach.

Comment: @Harel13 looks like pesher chavakuk? right in the middle there's וְחַדּוּ֙ מִזְּאֵ֣בֵי עֶ֔רֶב וּפָ֖שׁוּ פָּרָשָׁ֑יו וּפָֽרָשָׁיו֙ מֵרָח֣וֹק יָבֹ֔אוּ יָעֻ֕פוּ כְּנֶ֖שֶׁר חָ֥שׁ לֶאֱכֽוֹל

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe you are correct and it is indeed the Pesher Chavakuk scroll (מגילת פשר חבקוק). Note the line that says "הוא אשר אמר לרשת משכנות לא לו", which echoes Chavakuk 1:6 "כִּי הִנְנִי מֵקִים אֶת הַכַּשְׂדִּים הַגּוֹי הַמַּר וְהַנִּמְהָר הַהוֹלֵךְ לְמֶרְחֲבֵי אֶרֶץ לָרֶשֶׁת מִשְׁכָּנוֹת לֹּא לוֹ."

Answer (score 10):

The standard ideal length of a line is about 30 letters long, enough to write למשפחותיכם thrice per line ([Menachot 30a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.30a.12), [YD 272:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%91)). Lines that are too long are hard to follow and lines that are too short look like a note not a proper book. Some (Tosfot, etc.) say that the ~30 letter approximation can vary with the font size.